# Sum visible (or filtered) range in an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I need to filter and display the *COUNTIF* & *SUM* of both the *global range* and the *visible (or filtered) range*.

I can already display the *COUNTIF* & *SUM* of the *global range* with the following code.

```
AtmCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("X3:X4533"), ">0")
AtmSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("X3:X4533"))
```

I can also get the *COUNT* of the *visible (or filtered) range* as follows:

```
AtmCurrentCount = Range("X3:X4533").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

However, this still leaves the *SUM* of *visible (or filtered) range* outstanding.

```
AtmCurrentSum = ???
```

I really stuck. Please, can somebody help me?

Comment: This may not be the ideal solution but if you copy the used range onto a new sheet it will only copy the filtered data allowing you to do whatever calculations you need more easily

Comment: Not an option Ripster as the data changes too frequently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do what you want. Set visibleTotal to the appropriate data type for the total, and change the ws and rng objects to match what you have in your workbook.

```
Sub SumVisible()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim visibleTotal As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("B1:B7")

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=5

    visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    ' print to the immediate window
    Debug.Print visibleTotal
End Sub
```

In case you only want to sum part of the filtered range (e.g. you filter on column A but want the sum of column B), see this question and answer: [Copy/Paste/Calculate Visible Cells from One Column of a Filtered Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17531128/138938).

Answer (score 3):

If one need to COUNT the number of visible items in a filtered list, then use the SUBTOTAL function, which automatically ignores rows that are hidden by a filter.

The SUBTOTAL function can perform calculations like COUNT, SUM, MAX, MIN, AVERAGE, PRODUCT and many more (See the table below).  It automatically ignores items that are not visible in a filtered list or table. This makes it ideal for showing how many items are visible in a list, the subtotal of visible rows, etc. It also provide control rows hided manually manually.

The solution to your question would be to count the number of non-blank rows visible in Column A and Column B when a filter is active, use:

```
AtmCurrentSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, Range("$X$3:$X$4533"))
```

---

[image: Excel Subtotal Formula Arguments]

---

Points to remember when you apply SUBTOTAL formula:

- When function_num (First argument) is between 1-11, SUBTOTAL includes values that are hidden manually but ignore hidden by filter.
- When function_num is between 101-111, SUBTOTAL excludes all kind of hidden values.
- In filtered lists, SUBTOTAL always ignores values in hidden rows, regardless of function_num.
- SUBTOTAL ignores other subtotals that exist in references are ignored to prevent
  double-counting
- SUBTOTAL only work with vertical data values arranged vertically.
- In Horizontal Hidden Columns, values are always included and never ignored.

Comment: I want to utilize the 109 feature in the Data tab/Subtotal in VBA. Like: `Range(A1).Subtotal Groupby:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2)`. Do you know the corresponding argument for `109` to go into `Function:=`?

Comment: I believe, it will remain xlSum, however, to filter on visible cells, you need to use Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlcelltypevisible).SubTotal GroupBY:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2)

Comment: @jainashish Yes, it works fine. I put the VBA line you wrote in a function and call that function in a cell using formula: =AtmCurrentSum() .The only issue I experience is, when I click filter and change the visible cells, the function is not called and so the sum is not RE-calculated for new visible cells. I have to go into formula bar and press enter for re-calculation, the bad way! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want sum rather than sumif

```
AtmCurrentSum = application.worksheetfunction.subtotal(9, Range("X3:X4533"))
```

Comment: I've added the variable-thought it was self-explanatory ;-)

Comment: Not the variable ;) When I added your function `WorksheetFunction... it gives an error on the code

Comment: I've added the `application.` part though it isn't usually necessary

Answer (score 0):

The give function Sub SumVisible() did not worked for me instead i used Subtotal function.Caution use function number 109,102,104,105 to ignores hidden values. i.e. to calculates only on visible cells.

"https://support.office.com/en-us/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939"

```
aSum = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, CalcRange) 
aCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(102, CalcRange)
aMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(104, CalcRange)
aMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(105, CalcRange)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2016, this will work

Sum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("$D2:D" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))

9 specifies that you want to sum of visible rows
My data in which I had to find sum was in D column
Hope this will help :)

Answer (score -1):

I just came across this site.
https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-sum-values-in-an-excel-filtered-list/

The basic formula is 
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal('code number', 'range')
The formula you want is
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, range(x, y))