# Get the sum of a column for each specific filter in different column

Tags: excel, vba, macros

[image]
How can I sum all in the **Column "I"** for each filter in **Column "Q"** in **Sheet1**?
For example, referring on the sample sheet above;
Sum all the column I for 27744 only in Column "Q".
Sum all the column I for 27745 only in Column "Q"... and so on..

Then the sum will reflect on **Sheet2**, like below:
[image]

The Column "Q" entries in Sheet1 are always different, the above is only an example. Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835292/get-the-sum-of-visible-rows-in-vba) but I don't know if it can b used in this case.

I hope my question is clear. Thank you in advance for advice/help.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is wrong with what you have tried?  I would suggest either the Data/Subtotal wizard, or a Pivot Table..

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. I was also following [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835292/get-the-sum-of-visible-rows-in-vba), will do some experiment and will let you know

Comment: Just use a Pivot Table, as I suggested

Comment: That's a good idea actually. I'll just record a macro while doing the pivot. Let's how it will turn out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Would be nicer with cells and some tidying up but this should work -

```
Sub test()

    Dim dictSums As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictSums = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Set rngTarget = Sheet1.Range("Q1")

    Do While rngTarget.Value <> ""
        With rngTarget
            If Not dictSums.Exists(.Value) Then
                dictSums.Add .Value, .Offset(0, -8).Value
            Else
                dictSums(.Value) = dictSums(.Value) + .Offset(0, -8).Value
            End If
        End With
        Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    Dim varKey As Variant

    For Each varKey In dictSums.keys
        Debug.Print , varKey, dictSums(varKey)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I am having a compile error after trying the above. User-defined type not defined. Will try to experiment more using your suggested script. Thank you!

Comment: Go to Tools -> References -> scroll down the list and check Microsoft Scripting Runtime -> Ok