# Excel VBA Subtotal (sum) giving half the value compared to actual sum

Tags: excel, vba, function

so this is how my data looks like. It's actually up to column K. Column N and O are created by me via VBA. The data has 50,000+ rows

[image]

What I am trying to do is find unique values of column E by the filter, and then find the total time for that value by summing column K value.

This is my code for the same:

```
Sub Test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    

    ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E655360").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("N2"), Unique:=True
    
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lRow
    
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        Cells(i, 14).Value

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
        "<1:10:00"
        
    Cells(i, 15).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, Range("$K$2:$K$100000"))
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K999999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 27).PasteSpecial
    
    'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11
    'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5
      
    Next i

End Sub
```

Everything is working fine except the subtotal is giving me exactly half the value of the actual sum. I wasn't able to use SUM because it's counting the sum of hidden filtered out rows as well. I tested this via the SUM function, and the status bar sum value too. Interestingly, it's giving me exactly half value even when no filter is applied

For testing out, I checked the status bar sum value and also SUM(K:K) which both gave exactly double value from subtotal value

A simple fix might be to multiply the answers by 2, but I want to understand the actual problem as this quick fix can create problems later on

The number format for column K is [h]:mm:ss

This is Subtotal first argument syntax for quick reference:

[image]

Also please let me know if I can make this code more efficient somehow or change anything else to make it work well. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Why you never try sumIfs function, it not provide correct result?

Comment: This sounds like the perfect time to use a pivot table. You can set it to automatically group things based on Column E, and then set Column K as a value field and choose SUM.

Comment: You could get the effect you see if the subtotal cell was included in the sum range....

Answer (score 0):

In this case code 109 will be the same like 9 for the function:
Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal

The difference between 9 and 109 will be only when you hide rows manually, not with a table.

For reference see:
[See the subtitle "Difference in first arguments"](https://www.automateexcel.com/functions/subtotal-formula-excel/)

The possible solution it's make a range of visible cells and count the sum of this range. See the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835292/sum-visible-or-filtered-range-in-an-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before you place a reply, check if it is an answer for the question. In this case, you are trying to give a solution for the problem, but you are not replying to the question. Already another comments give solutions, but they are not answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happened is that the SUBTOTAL is including a SUM total at the bottom of the rows. Too late of a response for the owner of the post but this might help others.