# Copy visible cells vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a specific number of cells after apply a filter.

In my case, I need to copy the first 10 visible rows.

I tried with Range(Range("A5"), ActiveCell.Offset(10,3)).Select but not works, that copy hidden rows...

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy/Paste/Calculate Visible Cells from One Column of a Filtered Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531128/copy-paste-calculate-visible-cells-from-one-column-of-a-filtered-table)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to copy just the first visible 10 rows

Comment: Iterate on Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows, count to 10 adding each row to a new range that will contain the 10 rows.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and comment.

Comment: jivko, could you show me an example? Thanks