# Paste special with autofilter and unfilter after autofilter and paste is complete

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am using the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531128/copy-paste-calculate-visible-cells-from-one-column-of-a-filtered-table) to autofilter a table and paste the selected columns to another sheet.

It is doing exactly what I want it to do with one exception. I am copying from a table that uses filtered drop down menus. As a result, the following message pops up while copying: [The name already exists](http://samirvaidya.blogspot.com/2015/01/name-already-exists-dialog-in-microsoft.html)

The solution offered in this blog is not an option as the source table is dependent on the named values in it.

Is there an additional statement I can add to the below code that will make it paste special?

```
  copyRange4.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("E10")
```

If not, can something be added to select "Yes" without the pop up appearing at all?

Finally, after it pastes to my target, can an additional line be added to unfilter the source?

Comment: Kudos for qualified ranges :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `Alert` to by-pass the alert,

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    copyRange4.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("E10")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

---

To unfilter,

```
If (Range).AutoFilterMode Then
    (Range).ShowAllData
End If
```

Where `(Range)` is your range with filter.